# The correlation between depreciation rate and variance of output in RBC model

Tags: real-business-cycles

I would like know the correlation between depreciation rate and variance of output in RBC model.

As you know, the basic motion of capital is as follows.

$$K_{t+1} = (1-\delta) K_t + I_t$$

If $\delta$ increases, what could happen in the variance of output?

My intuition is this; if $\delta = 1$, explanatory variable is only $I_t$.

Thus, the variance of output might increase.

However, I do not know how exactly this is going.

Anyone has specifically economic explanation of this?